# Dozer - map class field to a flat representation

Tags: dozer

I've been googling and trying different dozer configuration options but so far couldn't find a simple solution... 
Problem is as follow:

```
class A {
 String test;
 B test2;
}
class B {
 String test3;
 String test4;
}

class C {
 String test;
 String test3;
 String test4;
}
```

Now I would like to map all of the fields from A (including B) to a flat representation in C.
Is it possible to map it using just configuration? The problem is that I need to map B in many different classes and I don't want to write a mapping like this for each of them:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>A</class-a>
    <class-b>C</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>test2.test3</a>
        <b>test3</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>test2.test4</a>
        <b>test4</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Would appreciate a solution for that :)

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use mapping IDs and "this". You need to define caseB only once and can reuse it.

```
<mapping map-id="caseB">
    <class-a>B</class-a>
    <class-b>C</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>test3</a>
        <b>test3</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>test4</a>
        <b>test4</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
<mapping>
    <class-a>A</class-a>
    <class-b>C</class-b>
    <field map-id="caseB">
        <a>test2</a>
        <b>this</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

found on dozer faq :

Can I map one field into another field that is nested n layers deep in the destination object?

Yes. Dozer supports dot notation for nested fields. As with other dozer field mappings, these are bi-directional.

```
<field>
  <a>someNestedObj.someOtherNestedObj.someField</a>
  <b>someOtherField</b>
</field>
```

[dozer FAQ](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/faq.html#mult-fields-to-single-field)